# Data type 'text' not accepting text

Tags: laravel, text, types, migration

In my Laravel application, I have this "history" column in my "download_history" table that was build as a json datatype in my migration, as seen here:

```
Schema::create('download_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();                        
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->json('history');
    $table->integer('user_id');
});
```

But i had to change it to text, as seen here:

```
Schema::table('download_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->text('history')->change();
});
```

But now, if I have any text inside this column, it simply won't print anything if i try to return it.. it only shows if it is a number.. I have no idea what could be causing this, or if I'm missing something.. I'm returning the data like this:

```
$history = DownloadHistory::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();                                                                         

return $history->history;
```

If the column is a number, let's say "100", it will show "100", but if it has ANY char, could be "100A" or simply "A", it doens't show anything...

Comment: Do you have anything in your `DownloadHistory` model that affects the output of the `history` column, like `protected $casts = ['history' => 'array'];` (or similar). Might be prudent to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72551120/edit) and include your model code  (Also can confirm easily via `php artisan tinker`, followed by `DB::table('download_history')->where('user_id', $userId)->first()->history` (replace `$userId` with a valid User ID; `DB::table()`) as it doesn't use your `DownloadHistory` model , which is nice for checking model functionality vs raw output rows)

Comment: Hmm.. I have EXACTLY that: "protected $casts = ['history' => 'array'];" in my model... I should change that... Sorry about not posting my model, i honestly completly forgot.. And i just wasn't thinking that it could affect the output of the column.

Comment: Sweet! What a guess  But yes, the `$casts` attribute tells Laravel to convert the `history` column to an array whenever it is accessed via a Model, like `DownloadHistory::first()->history` (or similar). `text` is the correct datatype you'd use with that cast, but unless the text in that column is a serialized array or JSON, it won't behave well 

Comment: I was trying to make it a JSON, but i couldn't make it work, so i'm going to try to do it as a text, and separate the entries to that column by regex...

Comment: I know what you mean  It's a little tricky to get it to work sometimes. Straight-forward example is `$array = [1, 2, 3, 'A', 'B', 'C']`, `DownloadHistory::create(['history' => $array]);`, then when you pull from the Model: `$downloadHistory->history`, it would be an Array `[1, 2, 3, 'A', 'B', 'C']` instead of a string representation, like `"[1,2,3,\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]"`. But if it's not a string representation of an array, it won't be able to convert it back properly. This can all be done manually with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`, so whatever works for you. Cheers!